# Показать скролл при наведении

Tags: html, javascript, css

Необходимо показывать скролл в div, в случае: если курсор наведен на div и скролл необходим.

Так сделано на ютубе, в левом блоке - подписки.

[**Некоторый набросок.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rBwj9/)

Comment: Кто-то умный поставил минус. Ну-ну.

Comment: @exec на меня не грешить.

Comment: Спасаю вопрос =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rBwj9/11/ так?

```
div {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Да, но есть проблема: промотай в самый низ убери курсор и наведи заново - у меня скролл вверх немного сдвигается.

Comment: Я понял из-за чего.

Comment: @exec ну это понятное дело будет происходить. Добавляйте padding и убирайте его же при событии hover. http://jsfiddle.net/rBwj9/16/ как то так. Вообще мне кажется, что это лучше на js реализовать.